# Microsoft SQL two databases on the same server to create a new joint table or DB

Tags: php, sql-server

well here I am the requirements changed a bit but still in the same scope, I am aiming to fetch data from mssql query and insert it in mysql, through php, I cant use linked servers(I have read only rights), please check the code and help me rectify it since I'm only an amateur.

```
<?php
//MSSQL Database Connection
$dbms = mssql_connect('host','dbusername','dbpass');
mssql_select_db('dbname', $dbms);

//MYSQL Database Connection
$dbmy = mysql_connect("host","dbusername","dbpass");
mysql_select_db('dbname', $dbmy);

require("connect.php");
$tableNameMy="ss_student";
$tableNameMs="ss_student";

$query = mssql_query("select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\n"
. "from ss_student\n"
. "inner join ss_sgi on B=s_k\n"
. "where sty=\'20152016\'",$dbms);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ss_student (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) VALUES" ,$dbmy;

while(list($A, $B, $C, $D, $E, $F, $G, $H) = mssql_fetch_array($result)){

$sql_rows[] = "('$A', '$B', '$C', '$D', '$E', '$F', '$G', '$H', NOW())";

}

mysql_query($sql . implode(',', $sql_rows) . ';');

echo "done";


?>
```

Comment: And you can use **`[database].[schema].[table]`** identifiers to refer DB objects across databases.

Comment: You should provide some samples what you have tried so far.

Comment: I guess I know how to query/join those two tables based by SELECT a.userID, b.usersName, b.usersEmail  FROM databaseX.dbo.TableA a inner join databaseY.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID, but how to write/update the result in db Y in a created table named XY?

Comment: @user5226786 could you please little format your Q what is input data and expected result

Comment: Database X: usernames and passwords, DatabaseY: username, name, email (username in X and Y are the same); I want to create a table in Y that holds username, password, name, email.